# AS3 For-each loop, checking next item

Tags: actionscript-3, foreach

I have a for-each loop:

```
    for each(var mcBlock:DisplayObject in blockArr){
       mcBlock.x -= 3;
           if((mcBlock.x + mcBlock.width) < mcBallTest.x - (mcBallTest.width /2)){
                trace(""+sec2+""+sec1+","+centiSec2+""+centiSec1+": Block Passed - Falling");}
```

Is there a way to check parts of the next mcBlock in blockArr?

Á la (mcBlock.x < mcBlock.next.x)

or

`for (var g:int = 0; g < blockArr.length; g++){
        if( blockArr[g].x < blockArr[g+1].x))`

I'd be using it to check whether the mcBallTest has passed a block and is infront of the next block. Thus, if the program runs faster than the ball moves, which it does, the code will not run if the ball is not between these blocks, and just not all the time after it passes the first block. Any help?

Oh, and it's getting late here, so apologies for unclear question if that may a fitting definition of this mission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You can use Cursors. Else you may just stick to a plain for loop.